# Google chrome dev panel shortcut for activate/deactivate breakpoints

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

Google chrome dev panel has many nice shortcuts and I've got used to them a lot.

There is almost only one thing what bothers me a lot and makes cry every time I have to do it:

I need to use mouse to switch state of all debug points at once.

For this I use now a button as shown on the following screenshot:

[image]

I wonder. Is there any other way to active/deactivate this button without mouse?

P.S.

Also this question is more about usage rather than programming I decided to ask it here because it's more likely to be answered by programmers.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no shortcut for enabling/disabling all breakpoints. You can open a ticket on http://crbug.com to request this feature be added though.

Comment: The breakpoints get automatically activated again sometimes (for example after modifying the code). Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac you can toggle breakpoints with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>

[image]

Comment: omg! it works on Linux as Ctrl+F8 . I guess they added this feature recently

Answer (score 1):

You must be able to toggle between enable/disable all the breakpoints (debugging rather) using Ctrl+F8 on any windows machine with Chrome as the browser of choice.